# Can't get divs central in parent

Tags: html, alignment

I have 6 `divs` that will hold images for products and I want them side by side in rows of three but then I want that centered.

This is the code I created for the parent and its all perfect apart from them being central.

```
<div id="parent" style="display:inline-block; margin:0 auto; width:730px">...</div>
```

As you can see, the divs are aligned left when compared with the horizontal rule..
[image]

Here is all of my code:[http://jsfiddle.net/FNkUP/](http://jsfiddle.net/FNkUP/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Remove the "display:inline-block" property, and it will work well. or make it "display:block".

```
div id="parent" style="display:inline-block;/*no need of this*/">...</div>
```

[For text align check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wikijames/FNkUP/5/)

Comment: I think this has worked but I have text under the divs and the text is now to the right of the divs. How do I get the text back under them?

Comment: give the text part "text-align:center". if not will work on it. write this to the parent element of the text holder

Comment: Nope that doesn't do it :'(

Comment: i updated fiddle , if still problem, update your fiddle with text also, i will give you changes according to it

Comment: no no sorry its not separate text for each div, its a few paragraphs below that run the width of 3 divs. My apologies, I should of been more clear

Comment: that's also no problem.  give each paragraph "width equal to total img size + padding and also give property to paragraph text-align:center and if you floated all 3 paragraphs that will do work fine

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38870/discussion-between-wikijames-and-adsy)

Answer (score 0):

just add this to your css

```
#parent
{
text-align:center;
}
```

or change the parent style tag  like

```
 style="display:inline-block; margin:0 auto; width:730px; text-align:center"
```

See your updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yv2WY/9/)

Comment: This should work but for some reason its only nudging the top right div about 3-4 pixels to the right :/

Comment: @Adsy i am looking into it with images